# How to set variable in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    start_date, 
    end_date,
    DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date should_be_live
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date should_be_live = 1
```

Is there a way to set a variable `should_be_live` = the expression `DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`. If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "variable" you mean "column in the result set", then yes.  You are basically doing it:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date,
       ( DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) as should_be_live
FROM mytable;
```

If by "variable", you mean that you want to define a column in the `select` and then filter on it, you cannot do that with `where` (unless you use a subquery).  You can use `having`:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date,
       ( DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) as should_be_live
FROM mytable
HAVING should_be_live = 1;
```

This use of `having` is a MySQL extension.

Comment: isn't there something like a `with` statement in mysql?

Comment: @David542 . . . Not yet.  That is expected with version 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately, you will have to repeat the same expression `DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` in your `WHERE` clause unless you are trying to access it in a outer query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    start_date, 
    end_date,
    DATE(now()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date as should_be_live
FROM mytable ) xxx
WHERE should_be_live = 1;
```

Column alias are accessible only to `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clause and not to `WHERE` clause (that to it's a MySQL extension and not  standard SQL)